# How to show that a given vector field is not complete in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose $X=(y^2,x^2)$ is a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2$, show that there is an integral curve starting from some point $(c,c)$ is not defined on all $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $X$ is not complete in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Note that the integral curves of this vector field are the curves $y^3=x^3+c$. In particular, the point $(c,c)$ moves along the line $y=x$ with $dx/dt=x^2$. The solution with $x(0)=c$ is $x(t)=c/(1-ct)$, which is only defined up to $t=1/c$.

Comment: I almost reach this answer too. The question is
1. Only when $y[t]\neq0$, we can show that the integral curves is $y^3=x^3+c$, how about the case of $y=0$?
2. Although the curve $x(t)=c/(1-ct)$ has a  singular time at  $t=1/c$, but can we claim that the solution can not be extended to $R$?

Comment: There's no problem with $y=0$. Note that we can write the differential equation in the form $x^2\,dx-y^2\,dy=0$. For your second question, note that the point shoots off to  infinity (say, when $c>0$) as $t\uparrow 1/c$.

Comment: If rather, we consider the integral curve starting from $(x_0,y_0)$, where $x_0\neq y_0$, then similarly, we obtain in this case:
\begin{cases}
    x(t)=\frac{1}{1/x_0- t}\\
    y(t)=-\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{1}{(x_0t-1)^3}\right)x_0^3-y_0^3}.
    \end{cases}
When $t\to 1/x_0$ (assume that $x_0\neq0$), we also have $x(t)\to\infty$, but it seems that it can be extended to $R$ by consider the Stream of vector field. see fig added in the original question.

Comment: @vanabel: looking at the streamlines cannot tell you that the vector field is complete. The key point is not the geometry of the streamlines, but the magnitude of the vector field along these streamlines - to be complete the flow trajectories must be defined for all *time*, not all space/length parameter.