# Solving a certain system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider the system of differential equations:
$$x'(t)= y(t)^2, y'(t) = x(t)^2, x(0) = a, y(0)=b, a, b \in \mathbb{R}.$$
How would one go about solving this system of differential equations?

Comment: What have you tried? Is there some combination f of x and y so that you get $f'$ can be written as a function of $f$.

Comment: @AHusain I have tried what you have suggested, but this did not get me anywhere.

Comment: You're in [this class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) of equations. In your case - just look at $x^2x'-y^2y'$.

Comment: @metamorphy Sure, I see that I can transform to get $x^2x' - y^2y'=0.$ But how does this give me the solution? I am sorry for my ignorance, but I know next to nothing about differential equations.

Comment: The LHS is $(x^3-y^3)'/3$. I think someone else should help you further...

Comment: @Dedalus It is half the solution. Having got $x^3(t)-y^3(t)=\textrm{const.}=a^3-b^3$, it's time to exclude either $x$ or $y$. Say, express $y$ using $x$ and plug it into the first of the equations. Sorry for refusing to write out the entire solution... you know why.

Comment: @metamorphy I do not see why you refuse to write out the solution. I am not getting the hint, unfortunately. $x^3(t)-y^3(t) = c$ is obvious, yes. Then it is clear I should use the equation $x'(t) = y(t)^2$ or $y'(t)=x(t)^2$ and plus this in in some way. I do not see how I do this in a nice manner and would appreciate either a full solution, or some hint.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have $x^3 - y^3 = a^3 - b^3$, you solve that for one of the variables, say $y = (x^3 - a^3 + b^3)^{1/3}$.  For convenience I'll write this as $y = (x^3 - c)^{1/3}$.  Now your equation for $x$ says
$$ x'(t) = (x^3-c)^{2/3}$$
This is separable, but unfortunately the integral necessary for the solution can't be done in closed form:

$$ t = \int \dfrac{dx}{(x^3-c)^{2/3}} + const$$

Comment: My original reason for asking the question was that this answer:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/536384/2394 (see the comments by van abel) seems to give quite explicit solutions to the differential equation, but I could not get them myself. Can one get these solutions from your answer?

Comment: van abel's solution is wrong for $c \ne 0$, as you can see by plugging it in to the differential equation.