# Prove that a specific vector field is not complete

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

I have the following vector field 
\begin{align} 
X(x,y)=(y^2,x^2)
\end{align}

and I need to prove it's not complete. I've seen several answer to this question, as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536370/how-to-show-that-a-given-vector-field-is-not-complete-in-mathbbr2?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947286/solving-a-certain-system-of-differential-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I'd like to understand a bit better it from a theroretical point of view and have a check on my approach

---

*My attempt*

As noticed in the other answers, the integral curves are $y^3=x^3+c$, and plugging this into the equation for $\dot x$ leads to

\begin{align}
\dot x  = (x^3-c)^{2/3}, \quad x(0)=x_0
\end{align}

It follows immediately that \begin{align} t(x)= \int_{x_0}^x \frac{ds}{(s^3-c)^{2/3}}\end{align}

As pointed out in the second of the linked answers, in order to have that the integral curve is defined for all times, I need this integral to be divergent, i.e.:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} t(x)=\int_{x_0}^\infty \frac{ds}{(s^3-c)^{2/3}}=+\infty$

At infinity, it is asymptotic to  $\frac{1}{s^2}$, therefore I have no problem.

**There could ie a problem if there exists $\bar{s}$ such that the denominator vanishes, but I can assume that such an $\bar{s}$ is outside the interval of integration**, indeed:

I know that the stationary solution is $x(t)=c^{1/3}$, provided $x_0=c^{1/3}$ and by existence and uniqueness thm. I can therefore consider $x_0$ to be grater or lesser than $c^{1/3}$.

Therefore the integral is converging, and then the integral curve is not defined for all times, therefore $X$ is not complete over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write $y^3 = x^3 + c$ then it should be $\dot{x} = (x^3 + c)^{2/3}$, and

$$ t = \int_{x_0}^x \dfrac{ds}{(s^3+c)^{2/3}} $$

Although the integrand blows up when $s^3+c = 0$, that's not really a problem because (if $c \ne 0$) the singularity is integrable.

The only stationary solution is $x=0, y=0$.

Comment: I can't understand why the singularity is integrable, could you be more explicit? I think my problem is exactly that

Comment: Is it because if $c=d^3$, then $(s^3+c)=(s+d)(s^2+sd+d^2)$, and hence in a neigbourood of $s=-d$ the integrand is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{(s-d)^{2/3}} $ and since $\frac{2}{3}<1$, then it's integrable, right?

Comment: Yes, that will do it.

Comment: Okay, one last thing: in the case $c=0$, the one which has been excluded, we have $\dot x =x^2$ and then given the initial condition $x_0$ I get $x(t)=\frac{x_0}{1-t}$ which is not defined for $t=1/c$, so  $X$ is not complete, right?